# Are relationships/interference between two piece of hardware on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, on-topic

A colleague claims that leaving on cell phone on top of an external conventional platter hard drive could damage the drive.

I'm not so sure about that, so I am interested in posting a question on superuser.

Would this be on-topic or off-topic?

Comment: damage how?  And over what sort of time frame?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Good questions.  Thanks!  I'm composing the question offline and will be sure to include those issues before I post it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this would be on topic - it is a question regarding computer hardware, and is within the scope. It has a canonical answer as well - yes it will cause damage, or no it will not cause damage.

To quote our help section on what is on topic:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about:
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that there needs to be a question before choosing the forum, and not the other way around.  There are likely more than one forum that would be appropriate depending on what the actual question is.

I agree in principle with the previous answer (Sheehan), but I disagree in the sense that there is no question to post yet.

This statement is hearsay without any reference to symptoms or a cause or severity. As there is no question to answer, no forum to post in.

Try to put the question in your own words and perhaps narrow it down to a field of study or industry.

If you put a magnet (speaker) near a magnetic medium (tape, cyl. hard drive), you could change the positioning of the magnetized particles. That is how data is written/erased.

With that info, even without a reference yet, you can formulate a question.  After that, picking a forum should be easy.

---

Electromagnetism + distance ( + time) + hard drive + cell phone = Physics / hardware/ personal and home computing question. This meets point 1 and 3 in Simon Sheehan's answer which I essentially agree with. As Sheenan quoted from the help section of SuperUser:

> ```
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about:
>
>     computer hardware,
>     computer software, or
>     personal and home computer networking
> ```

---

Right now I think the way you would phrase the question could be susceptible to be labelled "subjective" (quote from "Asking" section):

> What types of questions should I avoid asking?
>
> First, make sure that your question is on-topic for this site.
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be
>   asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to
>   explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of
>   course welcome in our real time web chat.)
>
> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
>   avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> ```
> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> ```